# How can run dusk test through php exec function

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-dusk

I have simple dusk Test when i run through terminal working fine

```
php artisan dusk tests/Browser/ExampleTest.php
```

I want to run this command through php file i have created test.php and added bellow code.

```
<?php
echo exec('php artisan dusk tests/Browser/ExampleTest.php');
?>
```

when run through terminal woking fine

```
php test.php
```

But when i run through browser like this 
http://localhost/dusk/test.php
output is **sh: : command not found**

Why dusk test is not running through browser how can do this.

Comment: echo shell_exec('php artisan dusk tests/Browser/ExampleTest.php');Warning: TTY mode requires /dev/tty to be read/writable.
sh: : command not found

Comment: did you specify the path to artisan correctly?

Answer (score 0):

You can call the laravel artisan commands directly from the laravel using

```
$exitCode = Artisan::call('dusk');
```

If you want to run it through the PHP you use `exec` or `shell_exec`

Make sure you give the right path to the binary e.g

```
<?php
echo exec('/usr/bin/php /your/project/path/artisan dusk tests/Browser/ExampleTest.php');
?>
```